# Why does pause return -1 and set errno?

Tags: c

According to the man page for pause, it returns -1 and sets errno to EINTR.

Why does it do this? I understood -1 to mean a failure, not something operating as normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only time `pause()` stops pausing is when it is interrupted, and that is a return on failure (to continue pausing).  So, correctly, it returns -1 to indicate that it failed to continue pausing.

Answer (score 1):

From the POSIX 2008 standard:

> Since pause() suspends thread execution indefinitely unless interrupted by a signal, there is no successful completion return value. A value of −1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.